# Store as Json Blob or Make Columns?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2017

I am building a "filter component" that displays all available filters for that "product type".

Pretty standard pretty much just think of bestbuy, amazon, craiglist style filter.

Right now I am focusing on how to generate the filter options(not how to handle once a user clicks on a filter option and it must then go off and filter the results down).

[image]

So I created a json object that has something like this,

which will create each header section(HardDrive,Ram Size, Number of CPU Cores), what type is it(checkboxes, textboxes), 
should the section be opened, 
should it have a search box in it.

```
 {
      type: "", // this is what type of filter it will be (textbox, checkboxes and etc)
      header: "Filter Header",
      property: "", // this maps it back to the column name in db used when filter is actually triggered.
      hasSearchBox: false, // some filter options are long so search box can be shown.
      isOpen: true, // controls if this filter should be in an open or closed state.
      for: ["What Products this filter applies to. Some of these filters are common between all products"]
    },
```

Now I need to figure out if I should store the above as is or if I should break it into a column format.

Ie

```
Filters Tbl
Id
ProductTypeId
type
header
property
hasSearchBox
isOpen
```

This does make it easier to add a new filter in the future, but I am bit concerned if some new option comes in that might only be for some filters and not others(ie lots of null columns) or if I need a more complex objects in the future(like setting the placeholder name for the textbox).

or if I should store it like this

```
ProductTypeTable
Id
FilterOptions <--- json from above gets store in here.
```

Comment: I would say if it is a column you know you will be using all the time create a column for it.  You can create indexes, and searches will be more efficient.  For the column/field you will not search on often or could be a sub value of one of the other columns (so something like a specific type is searched on, then this other field in the JSON (you dont have a field for) is depending aon that particular type, then you will have the records narrowed down already before having to search the JSON for this sub value

Comment: Well indexing won't be that critical at this time, as through all products that I have to support is going to be 30 filters and this won't grow any time soon.  A user will choose a Product Type and basically some way I have to get all the Filtering Options that is supported for that Product Type. Once I grabbed them it will the same filters till they change product type.

Comment: First, you say not at this time for indexing.  That is a big mistake to think that way.  It may not matter now, but your DB grows, gets big and then indexing becomes an issue and then you have to redesign your entire DB possibly to account for indexing.  As opposed to designing for that now (sometimes it takes longer but is worth it) so you designed it the right way from the start, and dont hvae to go back and rewrite/redo everything when you start having an issue.

Comment: Also you are referring to the product lookup table/values, but I was referring more to the products themselves that you will have tied to the producttypeid.  No clue what size your DB is going to be but if you have tons of products like amazon, you could have thousands/millions of records in a product table (only 30 product types maybe) but still millions of records in your product table that could benefit from the index (the index on the product type table, not a big deal).  When your products table grows though, thats when yo uwant it designed properly and tweaking indexes can help quicker..

Comment: than figuring out how to rewrite your entire database side of the application because you didnt take the time to think about a large dataset ahead of time and plan for performance issues and idexes.

Comment: "Well indexing won't be that critical at this time..."  <<< Be _very_ careful thinking like this. If it's not important now to create an index, it will become extremely important when someone starts asking why their website is slow. And if you are filtering on a large number of those fields in the JSON, I'd go ahead and import that JSON into a proper table.

Comment: Yes, I think we are talking about 2 different parts. I am talking about how to generate the list of filters (ie the side bar on amazon that shows a list of how many gigs of ram is on something). The actually products will be of course index(though I can do indexing even if I store them as json).

Comment: I updated my post, hopefully it makes more sense of what area I am working on. Just the generation of the filters not the actual filtering.